# C# build a websevice method that accepts POST methods like HttpWebRequest method

Tags: c#, post, service, web

i need a web service that accepts POST methods. An server that is accessing me is using POST method. 
It sends me an xml and i should response with some xml.

The other way, when i'm accessing him, i have managed with HttpWebRequest class and it works fine. It is done like:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(s.strMvrataUrl.ToString());
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
s.AddToLog(Level.Info, "Certifikat dodan.");
byte[] bdata = null;
bdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strRequest);
req.ContentLength = bdata.Length; 
Stream stremOut = req.GetRequestStream();
stremOut.Write(bdata, 0, bdata.Length);
stremOut.Close();
s.AddToLog(Level.Info, "Request: " + Environment.NewLine + strRequest);
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();
```

Now i would like to have a webservice that accepts POST method.
Does anyone has an idea how to do this. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Are you asking how to post to a web service or how to build a web service that accepts a post?

Comment: I think both would be helpful. Please help

Comment: If It is possible, consider switching to  asp.net web-api  .

Comment: I don't have experience with asp.net so i would rather do this with Web Service. For this kind of problems is asp.net used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP GET and HTTP POST may be enabled in the configuration. There exists a file called webconfig file in the root where in you have to add the following setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
                <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

ie inside the system.web tag.

Now in the web-service if you are intending to send an XML back you could design a struct of your wish which resembles the anticipated XML.
eg: To get an XML of following type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <Quote xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
        <object>Item101</object>
        <price>200</price>
    </Quote>
```

you have to return an object of following struct from the web-service:

```
public struct Quote
{
    public int price;
    public string object;
    public Quote(int pr, string obj)
    {
        price = pr;
        object = obj
    }
}
```

Now this can be received as response as string and then be parsed as you like.

===============================================================================

## **Edit I**

The following is a HelloWorld WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {  
      return "HelloWorld";
    }
```

[in case of struct change the return type to corresponding struct type]

The following is a function where you can POST to a URL and also send a xml file to the webservice[Use according to your need]:

```
public static XmlDocument PostXMLTransaction(string URL, XmlDocument XMLDoc)
    {


        //Declare XMLResponse document
        XmlDocument XMLResponse = null;

        //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
        HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest;

        //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
        HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;

        //Declare a generic view of a sequence of bytes
        Stream objRequestStream = null;
        Stream objResponseStream = null;

        //Declare XMLReader
        XmlTextReader objXMLReader;

        //Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
        objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

        try
        {
            //---------- Start HttpRequest

            //Set HttpWebRequest properties
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XMLDoc.InnerXml);
            objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

            //Get Stream object
            objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

            //Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream
            objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            //Close stream
            objRequestStream.Close();

            //---------- End HttpRequest

            //Sends the HttpWebRequest, and waits for a response.
            objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            //---------- Start HttpResponse
            if (objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Get response stream
                objResponseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                //Load response stream into XMLReader
                objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(objResponseStream);

                //Declare XMLDocument
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);

                //Set XMLResponse object returned from XMLReader
                XMLResponse = xmldoc;

                //Close XMLReader
                objXMLReader.Close();
            }

            //Close HttpWebResponse
            objHttpWebResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            //TODO: Add custom exception handling
            throw new Exception(we.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close connections
            objRequestStream.Close();
            objResponseStream.Close();
            objHttpWebResponse.Close();

            //Release objects
            objXMLReader = null;
            objRequestStream = null;
            objResponseStream = null;
            objHttpWebResponse = null;
            objHttpWebRequest = null;
        }
        //Return
        return XMLResponse;
    }
```

And the call would be like :

```
 XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
 XMLdoc.Load("<xml file locatopn>");
 XmlDocument response = PostXMLTransaction("<The WebService URL>", XMLdoc);
 string source = response.OuterXml;
```

**[If this was helpful or need more help please let me know]**

Comment: can you give me an example of WebMethod, how should she looks like? Cause i have managed to call with POST this WebMethod: [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(string str, string str1)

Comment: Tnak you for your answer. This is a client side function i have no problem with this. I have problems with my WebService [webmethod], how should my webservice method look like to acccept such POST calls?

Comment: @MarkoLeben: I heve given an example up in my Edit I:       [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {  
      return "HelloWorld";
    }

Answer (score 0):

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267:

> HTTP GET and HTTP POST may be enabled by editing the Web.config file
>   for the vroot where the Web service resides. The following
>   configuration enables both HTTP GET and HTTP POST:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have done this. Belive i have searched the net. But how should i access it with POST method with some xml?