# Not able to get data from web service using json asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a web service in my project and calling it from another page using jquery.
But not getting data from web service, I have checked using breakpoint in web service its not getting hit from jquery call. My code is.

web service

```
namespace DOC_HTML
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for JsonService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class JsonService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public static string DocTypeList()
    {
        MastersService MS = new MastersService();   
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(MS.DocumentTypeList()));

        List<dropDown> listDocType = new List<dropDown>();

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dropDown objst = new dropDown();
                objst.Id = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["docCode"]);
                objst.Name = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["docName"]);
                listDocType.Insert(i, objst);
            }

        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jscript = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return jscript.Serialize(listDocType);
    }

}

public class dropDown
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Web Page Code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadData();
    });

    function loadData() {  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../JsonService.asmx/DocTypeList",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsdata = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    $.each(jsdata, function (key, value) {
                        $('#<%= ddlDocType.ClientID %>').append($("<option></option>").val(value.Id).html(value.Name));
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        });          
    }

</script>
```

[image: error image]

Comment: The clue is in the response: `Unknown web method DocTypeList`. Have you debugged the reasons why the method is not being found?

Comment: As you are not passing any data to your web service , remove that line  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` . Sometimes that also causes the problem .

Comment: i have tried not working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how to debug it.

Comment: got solution i just removed static from web method and it works....

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854631/c-sharp-build-a-websevice-method-that-accepts-post-methods-like-httpwebrequest-m) question. I suspect your JQuery ajax call is looking for a method which accepts POST, but there may be none.