# SOAP HTTP Post Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

If I have a C# ASP.Net Webservice, I can see that I can call it via **HTTP Post** on localhost but not on the actual web address (at least **its not shown in the soap examples**). 
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854631/c-sharp-build-a-websevice-method-that-accepts-post-methods-like-httpwebrequest-m) that I can enable it by using this piece of web config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
                <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My question is now:

Am I facing any security concerns when enabling this feature ? And if not, why is it not enabled in the first place ?

Comment: how are you binding the webservice to your ip address and port??

Comment: Its not "my" ip address. Its the actual web address and thats made on the Server in the IIS

Comment: so have you bound IIS to the correct IP address. Is there a DNS entry on the web for the web address?

Comment: Its in the local intranet and I can reach the example page, so yes everything should be bound correctly :)

Comment: Okay cool. I'm out of ideas, but this should narrow down to some small config

Comment: I dont know how some small config can be the answer to : Am I facing any security concerns when enabling this feature ?

Comment: Oh, sorry I slightly misread your question. Basically no you're not going to face any security issues at all, as long as you follow OWASP. So, SSL encryption, SQL Injection attacks, Session Hijacking, Over Posting.